# detect client connection closed in the grpc server

Tags: c++, asynchronous, grpc

In the `unary RPC` example provided in the grpc Github ([client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc)) and ([server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc)), is there any way to detect client's closed connection?

For example, in `server.cc` file:

```
std::string prefix("Hello ");
reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

// And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
// memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
// the event.
status_ = FINISH;
int p = 0,i=0;
while(i++ < 1000000000) { // some dummy work
        p = p + 10;
}
responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
```

With this dummy task before sending the response back to the client, server will take a few seconds. If we close the client (for example say with `Ctrl+C`), the server does not throw any error. It simply calls `Finish` and then deallocates the object as if the `Finish` is successful.

Is there any `async` feature (handler function) on the server-side to get us notified that the client has closed the connection or client is terminated?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

But now guys from gRPC team works hard to implement callback mechanism into C++ implementation. As I understand it will work the same way as on Java implementation( https://youtu.be/5tmPvSe7xXQ?t=1843 ).

You can see how to work with future API with next examples: [client_callback.cc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/qps/client_callback.cc) and [server_callback.cc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/qps/server_callback.cc)

And the point of your interest there is `ServerBidiReactor` class from `::grpc::experimental` namespace for server side. It have `OnDone` and `OnCancel` notification methods that maybe can help you.

Another interesting point there is that you can store a pointers to connection object and send notifications to client at any time.

But it still have many issue and I don't recommend to use this API in production code.
Current progress of C++ callbacks implementation you can see there: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/projects/12#card-12554506

Comment: Does streaming grpc in C++ provide such callback ?

Comment: No. With streaming you can't store connection provider on server. With current  implementation for C++ you can work only by next scheme: Client make a request -> Server receive it and prepare an answer(s). -> Server send a reply(s) with last package - "Finish" command -> TCP connection closed(and no way to save it for future)